# How can I create a big file in Google Drive with Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to create a big file in Google Drive using Google Apps Script. This file merges three files. My code is:

```
    function unirFicheros(idDirectorio,nombreFichero, numeroFicheros){
      var nombreTotal=nombreFichero;
      var strTotal="";
      var docTotal = DocsList.createFile(nombreTotal, strTotal);
      Utilities.sleep(5000);
      Logger.log("SE CREA TOTAL: " + numeroFicheros);
      for(var i=1;i<=numeroFicheros;i++){
           Logger.log("ENTRO EN EL FOR");
           var nombrePartes=nombreFichero+i+".csv";
           Logger.log("NOMBREPARTES: " + nombrePartes);
           var id=listFilesInFolder(idDirectorio,nombrePartes);
           var docPartes = DocsList.getFileById(id);
           Utilities.sleep(5000);
           Logger.log("Existe el fichero");
           var str = docPartes.getContentAsString();
           Logger.log("UNE LA CADENA");
           strTotal = strTotal+str;
           Utilities.sleep(5000);
           docTotal.replace(strTotal);
           Utilities.sleep(30000);
        }
        return docTotal;
    }
```

The error occurs is:

> Ejecución fallida: El archivo backup_actuaciones_PROD supera el tamaño de archivo máximo permitido.
>   (Execution failed: File backup_actuaciones_PROD file size exceeds the maximum allowed.)

I trying to generate my file without format because internet says that these files are bigger. Actually, my file have 44 MB, but i need 427 MB.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

[`DriveApp.createFile()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createFile%28String,String%29) includes a note that it... `Throws an exception if content is larger than 10MB`. I expect that this limitation also affects `DocsList.createFile()` and `DocsList.replace()`.

You might have better results by avoiding the need to handle the entire contents of `docTotal`. Use [`File.append()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/file#append%28String%29) to add the content of each file:

```
       ...
       var str = docPartes.getContentAsString();
       Logger.log("UNE LA CADENA");
       docTotal.append(str);
       ...
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this solution don't function, the message is the same. I don't understand because google says that can save big files in google drive, but i can't create a document larger than 44 megabytes

Comment: That's unfortunate. I suggest you enter a report in the [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/).