# Create a large zip file in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I appreciate that other posters have alluded to this issue before. I know how to create a zip file comprised of a number of other folders and files using `Utilities.Zip`. The problem is the **size** of the resultant file. Because the resultant file is larger than **10MB** (as, let's face it, any zip file containing more than a few images will be) `createFile` fails (throwing an exception as described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createFile(String,String))).

It appears that the Advanced Services `Drive.Files.insert` is subject to the same limitation.

Is it really true that there is *absolutely no way* to programmatically create a file larger than 10MB in Google Drive? It's a real stumper for the app I'm writing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Previously there was a way to append to a file, that method expects a string as a parameter. Trying to pass it the contents of a binary file will result in garbled and useless output. This was the only way that I found to defeat the 10MB per file limit. See reference:

- http://www.neant.ro/2014/02/backup-files-on-google-drive-using-google-apps-script/
- [How can i create a big file in google drive with google app script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765474/how-can-i-create-a-big-file-in-google-drive-with-google-app-script)

However the function `file.append()` is [deprecated on December 11, 2014](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/file#append%28String%29) by Google.

Thus I don't think you can get what you want now from my perspective. Let me know if anything I was missing about it. Hope it helps.